# Bone moves the entire mesh

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

I made a decent looking bolt gun in blender and I'm trying to add movement to the guns string. I added a rig to the bow part with a 2 sets of bones going along the Z axes.
Then I set one bone to the string as a way to pull the string back. I set automatic weights in parenting to both the string and bow. Here's my problem, when I pull the string back, the whole mesh goes with it and stretches. How can I set this up so it will work right? Is it possible that the string needs to be set up as it's own object? It isn't even listed as "cylinder" in the hierarchy.

Comment: Ok, are you talking Bolt-Action rifle, or Crossbow/Arbalest? Also, some details and screenshots, and maybe .blend, would really help.

Comment: .Or a cork-gun?

Comment: It's a crossbow with arrow basically. ☺ It's just a shorter version of a crossbow. Looks Kinda like a hand gun. I don't have a way to post pictures cause I'm using my phone as access to the net.

Comment: I made it in blender cycles.

Comment: @Tony may you post pictures? we can't really see your problem.